# How do I input values into a mysql table using php when there is a restriction?

Tags: php, mysql, insert, where-clause

I'd like to insert data into a table only when certain values in that table's (sessionid) row match another variable. I am struggling to put together the INSERT statement.  The approach I am taking: retrieve all the rows in the table that match the criteria (retailer=$retailer) and then iterate through those rows inputting the variable options into the sessionid table.

```
$retailer = $_GET['retailer'];
$options = $_GET['options'];
$session = session_id();

//mysql connection stuff goes here

$query = "
SELECT *
FROM `sessionid`
WHERE `retailer` = '$retailer'
";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      mysql_query("INSERT INTO sessionid (options) VALUES('$options')");
    }
```

Is the syntax correct for me to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Not your answer, but: Consider using Zend Framework with Zend Db to abstract your DB queries or at least escape $options and retailer with http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php or everybody is able to drop your database with a simple sql injection.

Comment: insert would be for a new record, update is for an existing row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you maybe looking for the [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html) command instead?

```
UPDATE   sessionid
SET      options = $options
WHERE    retailer = $retailer
```

By the way, I would look in to using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) as it's more secure than pushing `$_GET` values in a database.

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=MYDATABASE', 'username', 'password');

$db->prepare('UPDATE sessionid SET options = ? WHERE retailer = ?');

$db->execute(array($options, $retailer));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WHERE clause in mysql to do this. If you are changing an existing row, you actually want UPDATE, not INSERT.

```
UPDATE sessionid SET options=$options where retailer = $retailer
```